# Should I declare member variables that are going to be used by C functions as static?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

If I have a class, `A`, with a member `m_data`, Do I need to declare it `static` or with C linkage when I *know* it's going to be used in a third-party C function?

```
struct Data
{    
    int a;
    float b;        
    double c;
};

class A
{
public:
    Data m_data;
};
```

**Example:**

I have a class, `Foo`, that is doing something like this (with FreeRTOS timers):

```
class Foo
{
public: 
    void stop_timer() { xTimerStop(&m_timer, 0); }
private:
    TimerHandle_t m_timer;
}
```

I'm debugging some low-level weirdness, and I am worried (maybe incorrectly) that passing C++ member variables to the FreeRTOS functions is causing me problems.

Comment: You mean that somewhere in your code you'll do something like `some_c_function(&a_object.m_data)`? In that case, there's nothing particular to do (assuming that both the C function and your C++ code have the same idea of `Data` layout, which is usually the case).

Comment: In short "no". Why do you think you might need to?

Comment: Hold-up, I'll add a more specific example of what I'm worried about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
public: 
    void stop_timer() { xTimerStop(&m_timer, 0); }
private:
    TimerHandle_t m_timer;
}
```

You do **not** need to add `static` to `m_timer` here. As `stop_timer()` is a member function of `class Foo`, I presume that every instance of `Foo` will have its *own* timer that it will pass to `xTimerStop()`, not one timer shared between all instances of `class Foo` -- which is (the only thing) what `static` would achieve.

You do not need any declaration of `extern "C"` here either; the C part (the implementation of `xTimerStop()`) does not "see" the symbol `m_timer` anyway; all it "sees" is the *address* of it (passed by the `stop_timer()` code), so linkage is irrelevant at this point. (But see my second comment below on callbacks, which *do* need `extern "C"`.)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought and why I'd designed `Foo` this way, but was confusing myself. To expand on your last point, as long as I pass handles (pointers) around, linkage is always irrelevant, regardless of what the C functions do with the data internally?

Comment: @EdKing: Linkage (`extern "C"` or not) refers to *symbols*. Basically, whether a function name gets C++ name mangling (encoding the parameter list in the linker symbol) or not. Passing pointers around does not touch on the matter of symbols. Besides, if you had gotten the linkage wrong, the linker would have complained noisily, and you wouldn't *have* a binary to debug. ;-)

Comment: @EdKing: It is somewhat different for callback functions, i.e. when you tell C code "call this function when something happens" (e.g. `pthread_create()`'s start function, or `qsort()`'s compare function). Here, `extern "C"` *also* handles the calling convention used, which is why you would need to `extern "C"` any function that gets called from C space despite the C code *still* only "seeing" the (function) pointer.

Comment: The distinction between passing the address or value in relation to the underlying symbol was something I'd not really given much consideration to, so thanks for that. The callback stuff is interesting too, as FreeRTOS allows empty callbacks to be used with their Timers (which I have), but which I did not `extern "C"`. Perhaps this creates an internal issue, because it certainly compiles.

Comment: @EdKing: That is a possibility. You see, all other things aside, a C++ member function implicitly gets a `this` pointer passed as first parameter. Perhaps your "empty" callback, when returning, removes a `this` pointer from the stack that wasn't put there in the first place by the FreeRTOS C function call. That would play merry hell with your stack contents... perhaps put "canaries" there (known values) and check your stack contents in the debugger prior and after such a callback...